# Codeigniter 3 go back to last page after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried many different things to get this to work and this is what I currently have:

```
// save the redirect_back data from referral url (where user first was prior to login)
  $this->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $this->agent->referrer() );  

// user is authenticated, lets see if there is a redirect:
      if( $this->session->userdata('redirect_back') ) 
      {
          $redirect_url = $this->session->userdata('redirect_back');  // grab value and put into a temp variable so we unset the session value
          $this->session->unset_userdata('redirect_back');
          redirect($redirect_url, 'refresh');
      }
      else
      {
          redirect('/', 'refresh');
      }
```

The problem with this is sometimes there is no referral url. For example I allow video/image uploads. If the user is on the home page page and they click on the upload videos button and they're not logged in it redirects them to the log in page and refreshes and there is no longer a referral url. I want the user to be redirected back to the upload videos page because they tried to access this page but could not because they were not logged in.

Does any know why this is happening?

Comment: You can use `current_url()` function from url helper.

Comment: so would I replace `$this->agent->referrer()` with `current_url()`?

Comment: I would try that in setting session. It is current url controller/method produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in the constructor for each controller of the logged in areas. For example:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    /*
     * First check to see if they are logged in
     * if not redirect to login in page with
     * redirect back information
     */
        if (!$this->session->userdata('uid')) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'login?ref=account');
        } else {
            /*
             * if they are logged in, load helpers, models, libs
             * and proceed with viewing normally
             */
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                //etc.
        }
}
```

I use a query string here but you can just as easily use uri segments. The login controller then picks up the query string and upon successful login, uses it to send them back. The advantage is they always redirect back to where you want them to go, because you always know where they were based on your explicit code. The disadvantage is its a little more maintenance since you have to make sure all you "protected" areas have the appropriate redirect parameters. You can make this more flexible using current_url() as was mentioned in the comments. You also have to deal with data in the url which the user can mess with, but if you've designed everything else correctly, that shouldn't be much of an issue. I like this method because it explicitly keeps me in control of flow and I can adjust each controller to go where I want and return to where I want.